# SQL: create new table with distinct value and max/min values for other columns w/in an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example:
Suppose the original table contains the following values

```
AcctNbr StatusDate
------------------
123     01/01/2012    
123     01/01/2013
123     12/11/2011
987     01/01/2009
```

The SQL would create a new table containing

```
AcctNbr EarliestStatusDate LatestStatusDate
-------------------------------------------
123     12/11/2011         01/01/2013
987     01/01/2009         01/01/2009
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this. I have a method that works, but it takes an unacceptably long time. Does anyone have any optimization tips. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DROP TABLE loopTemp
DROP TABLE reportTemp

CREATE TABLE loopTemp
(   ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    AcctNbr varchar(50),
)

CREATE TABLE reportTemp
(
    AcctNbr varchar(50),
    EarliestStatus Date,
    LatestStatus Date 
)

INSERT INTO loopTemp
SELECT DISTINCT AcctNbr
FROM AutoStatusHistory 

DECLARE @COUNTER AS INT
SET @COUNTER = 1

DECLARE @MAX AS INT
SET @MAX = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM loopTemp)

WHILE @COUNTER < @MAX BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS varchar(50)
    SET @ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 
        (SELECT AcctNbr FROM loopTemp WHERE ID = @COUNTER)

    DECLARE @EARLIESTSTATUSDATE AS DATE
    SET @EARLIESTSTATUSDATE =   (SELECT MIN(NewStatusDate)
                                 FROM AutoStatusHistory 
                                 WHERE AcctNbr = @ACCOUNT_NUMBER)

    DECLARE @LATESTSTATUSDATE AS DATE
    SET @LATESTSTATUSDATE =     (SELECT MAX(NewStatusDate)
                                 FROM AutoStatusHistory 
                                 WHERE AcctNbr = @ACCOUNT_NUMBER)

    INSERT INTO reportTemp
    VALUES (@ACCOUNT_NUMBER, @EARLIESTSTATUSDATE, @LATESTSTATUSDATE)

    IF (@COUNTER % 1000) = 0 BEGIN
        PRINT @COUNTER 
    END -- IF

    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
END -- WHILE 

DROP TABLE loopTemp
```

Comment: It seems that your code example doesn't produce upper result table because your code also adds as many `null` records as there are missing IDs between `AcctNbr = 1` and `MAX(AcctNbr)`. You may have consecutive IDs in your DB table so may not be aware of this, but if one ID gets removed you'll get `null` records in your resulting table. Is that desired or not? If it is, then it would make resulting select statement a tiny bit more complicated than the `group by`... But it would still be much much more simple than your current code that's way too complex for such a simple task.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, this should be extremely simple:

```
SELECT AcctNbr, MIN(StatusDate) AS EarliestStatusDate, 
    MAX(StatusDate) AS LatestStatusDate
FROM myTable
GROUP BY AcctNbr
```

Comment: +1 I must be missing something as well. I haven't even checked that horrendous TSQLfor such a simple task into great detail but it seems that it does practically the same thing just that it stores results in a concrete table... It also seems that it stores IDs missing from the original table...

Comment: @user2195387: If this answer helped you, you should accept it as such (click the tick) and give back to the community that helped you. Just saying as I can see you're new around here...

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using SQL Server.  For this, you can do:

```
select AcctNbr, min(StatusDate) as EarliestStatusDate,
       max(StatusDate) as LatestStatusDate
into ReportTemp
from AutoStatusHistory
group by AcctNbr
```

The `into` statement saves the results into a table.  You might want to use an actual temporary table, with the syntax:

```
into #ReportTemp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT *
INTO TableName
FROM (
SELECT AcctNbr, MIN([Status Date]) AS EarliestStatusDate, 
    MAX([Status Date]) AS LatestStatusDate
FROM myTable
GROUP BY AcctNbr
) RequiredData
```

Comment: Why use subquery when `into` can be added to original `select` statement?

Comment: Thank you all. This was embarrassingly simply.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Ouch! Thanks for pointing out that! Guess I was too overwhelmed by the simplicity of the question!